# How to convert to emotions from post title in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In content editor wordpress, I can convert to emotions `:)`, `;)`, `:(` ...

But in title I can't convert to emotions, How to ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the function [`convert_smilies()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/convert_smilies) when displaying your title.

Instead of using `the_title()`, use:

```
echo convert_smilies( get_the_title() );
```